# How can old sessions in /var/lib/php/session/ be flushed?

Tags: php, session

I noticed recently that I have a huge number of sessions in there - 1.3M sessions (as determined from `ls -l /var/lib/php/session/ | wc -l`). My weekly visits are only in the single-digit thousands, so this seems crazy high - I'm assuming it is somehow saving the sessions and never flushing the old ones for some reason.

Are there relevant settings in the php.ini that control these?

Comment: Garbage Collection should be automatic so there must be a inherent problem somewhere in your environment. another alternative is move away from a file based session storage and look into database session handler.

Otherwise here is a link to the core session configuration items that impact garbage collection http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability

Comment: What distro are you running? In Debian-based systems, this is handled by a cron job. See the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php for some good information

Comment: The issue comes from the duration of the sessions you implemented on your server cpde. Reduce that in your code.

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears I actually *was* generating 1.3M sessions in a week, despite my # of visitors not being nearly that high. it seems every request is generating a new session ID, including on an API I provide, so that is becoming a runaway problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, discussion of this can be [found in the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-gc.php):

You want to look at all the session.gc_ settings, as those are the variables that effect how likely it is that garbage collection is running.

With that said, something is clearly wrong, as it seems like your session files are not being deleted.

You do need to factor in the session.gc_maxlifetime setting in your php.ini file, as no file will be deleted until that number of seconds since file creation has passed.  If your gc_maxlifetime is too long, files will accumulate.

This script is a recommended cron - oriented command line php script that can be installed and run daily or weekly to run the garbage collector.  I would start with that and see what happens.

There could be permissions issues that are actually preventing the garbage collector from deleting the sessions, so starting with a manual run of this program and seeing what happens to the number of session files would be a good start.  If you have php7.1 this is the recommended code from the manual.

```
<?php
// Note: This script should be executed by the same user of web server process.

// Need active session to initialize session data storage access.
session_start();

// Executes GC immediately
session_gc();

// Clean up session ID created by session_gc()
session_destroy();
?>
```

A program for older versions of php that should work in a similar fashion would be:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

The idea here is that you are guaranteeing that the garbage collector will run by making the probability 100% for this script.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! To be noted it only works with PHP7 and I'm lagging behind on 5.6, but I was able to get the same result just by modifying the php.ini directly to set the gc denominator to 1. It appears GC is working properly, and the real culprit is that I actually *was* generating 1.3M sessions in a week (the expiry time set for my sessions), despite my # of visitors not being nearly that high. it seems every request is generating a new session ID, including on an API I provide, so that is becoming a runaway problem.

Comment: Makes sense.  PHP sessions do depend on a cookie being set.  Either that your you need to pass the session id as a get parameter.  That is not ideal for use in a REST api.